# Proof related to a general answer to the normal vector of a surface?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was following a tutorial on openGL and eventually reached a point where a non-intuitive algorithm was used. I tried to prove it and when that failed I resorted to google.

This was the first hit: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html and [this expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVmhP.png) would completely explain how the algorithm works, however I can't find any proof online. I'd be grateful if someone could provide some help.

Comment: What exactly is the difficult in your understanding, do you mean why that expression is a normal vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Faraad's notes on page 10, the very last formulas. It shows the equations for tangents on curves. What are those curves? They are they curves you get when you cut your surface defined by $z=f(x,y)$ with a plane parallel to the $x$-$z$-plane and the $y$-$z$-plane, resp. This is shown in the pictures above on page 10.

Tangents on curves is something you should be familiar with. As expected, those tangent equations involve derivatives. In this case, they are partial derivatives, because we are dealing with a function of 2 variables, but each considered curve only has one of them varying, the other is fixed.

Each tangent has a direction vector in the 3D-space. For the first tangent, which is for the curve parallel to the $x$-$z$-plane, the $y$-value never changes (that is what it means to be parallel to the $x$-$z$-plane). So the $y$ component of that direction vector is zero:

$$\vec{v_{x,z}}(a,b) = (?,0,?)$$

What are the other coordinates? They are only determined up to a constant, because a direction vector can be multiplied by any positive constant and it is still the same direction. Now it's time to remember a thing about a derivative: It measures at which rate the function changes (at least near the point where the derivative was calculated). Since $z$ is the dependent variable and $x$ the independent one, the complete direction vector can look like this

$$\vec{v_{x,z}}(a,b) = (1,0,f_x(a,b))$$

If the independent variable $x$ changes by 1 (small) unit (and $y$ doesn't change), the dependent variable $z$ changes by a $f_x(a,b)$ units.

Now exactly the same argument with $x$ and $y$ interchanged can be made. We have a curve that is created by cutting the surface with a plane parallel to the $y$-$z$-plane...

In the end, we get another direction vector for another tangent on our surface

$$\vec{v_{y,z}}(a,b) = (0,1,f_y(a,b))$$

Now we have 2 direction vectors that lie both in our tangent plane. The normal vector $\vec{n}$ must be orthogonal to both of them. Now $\vec{v_{x,z}}$ and $\vec{v_{y,z}}$ are not parallel (any multiple of $\vec{v_{x,z}}$ cannot produce a value of 1 in the $x$-component, and similar the other way around).

So we have 2 non-parallel vectors and we are looking for a third that is orthogonal to both of them. Since we are working in 3 dimensions, there is exactly one of them (up to multiple).

You can easily check that

$$\vec{n} = (f_x(a,b),f_y(a,b),-1)$$

is orthogonal to both:

$$ \vec{n} \cdot \vec{v_{x,z}} = (f_x(a,b),f_y(a,b),-1) \cdot (1,0,f_x(a,b)) = f_x(a,b) \cdot 1 + f_y(a,b) \cdot 0 + (-1) \cdot f_x(a,b) = f_x(a,b) - f_x(a,b) =0$$

and a very similar calculation shows that $ \vec{n} \cdot \vec{v_{y,z}} = 0$ as well. So $\vec{n} = (f_x(a,b),f_y(a,b),-1)$ is indeed the normal vector to the tangent plane on your surface.

If you ask: "How could I know which vector $\vec{n}$ to choose?", then just look at page 11 of Faraad's notes and the cross product of vectors : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Answer (score 0):

I have it in my notes that I am working on [here](https://explorationsingeometry.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/differential-geometry-notes22.pdf), look at pages 10 and 11.